# Como ignorar Pastas/Diretórios no GIT? Ex: .metadata , .recommenders

Tags: git

Estou com um projeto no .git no qual acredito ser necessário ignorar alguns arquivos. Porém, coloco o comando e a pasta continua aparecendo no git status. Fiz da seguinte manera:

criando arquivo gitignore

```
touch .gitignore
```

Incluindo arquivos/diretórios no .gitignore a serem ignorados

```
# ignora os arquivos com extensões 
.gitignore
# ignora quaisquer diretórios chamados "metadata"
.metadata/
.recommenders/
```

Só que ao dar o git status continuam aparecendo as mudanças que deveriam não aparecer, pois o .gitignore sumiu do git status porém a pasta continua aparecendo.

[image: Pasta ainda aparecendo no git status]

Answer (score 9):

Só usando o gitignore mesmo. Atente que se você já adicionou os arquivos no repositório, precisa removê-los.

```
git rm --cached -r /.metadata
```

Use o argumento `-r` (recursive) quando for remover uma pasta e todos os arquivos dentro dela.

Answer (score 6):

O gitignore serve exatamente para isso, crie ele na raiz do seu projeto com o nome `.gitignore` e dentro dele insira o codigo.

```
# lembre de colocar o nome da pasta sem o ponto na frente
# Para ignorar todos arquivos e sub-pastas localizados na pasta metadata/plugins/
metadata/plugins/nome-do-plugin

# Para ignorar todos os arquivos e sub-pastas da pasta metadata/
metadata/
```

Se ainda tiver duvidas veja esse [post](https://fjorgemota.com/gitignore-ou-como-ignorar-arquivos-no-git/) que explica bem como resolver esse problema.