# Commit de alterações em Xamarin Forms

Tags: git

Toda vez que altero ou crio um novo arquivo no meu projeto em xamarin forms e faço Clear e Rebuild no projeto, ele gera arquivos na pasta de debug, e no momento de fazer o commit para o repositorio tenho que subir esses arquivos do debug.

Como ignorar esses arquivos para subir apenas o que alterei ou criei de fato?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual é o sistema de versionamento?

Comment: @LINQ a aba da janela do print chama `unstaged files`, acho que é git!

Comment: Faz sentido, @IgorVenturelli. De qqr forma, eu já votei na sua resposta XD Só acho bom lembrar o AP que ele vai precisar remover os arquivos do repo. Agora que eles já foram adicionados, não adianta só colocar no gitignore

Comment: @LINQ Boa! Resposta editada =) Valeu!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isso não tem a ver com Xamarin ou .NET.

Isso está diretamente relacionado com seu versionador de código fonte.

Acredito que você esteja usando git, certo?

Existe um arquivo chamado `.gitignore` que fica no seu repositório local. Lá você pode informar quais arquivos e pastas devem ser ignorados.

Caso já tenha commitado os arquivos e pastas que não deseja commitar é necessário removê-los do repositório. O fato de incluir no `.gitignore` não vai removê-los de lá. 
[Essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/193854/ignorando-arquivos-pelo-gitignore) e [essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/204511/como-ignorar-pastas-diret%C3%B3rios-no-git-ex-metadata-recommenders) pergunta estão respondidas também sobre como remover arquivos do repositório.

---

Veja mais sobre como ignorar arquivos no git e como montar seu `.gitignore` [aqui](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).

Comment: Igor, se achar interessante linkar, tem estas duas perguntas aqui no site que falam sobre remover arquivos dos repos https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/193854/18246 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/204511/18246

Comment: Obrigado, era isso mesmo o problema.

Comment: Show @LINQ! Resposta editada.